# Thread safe for static function

Tags: java, android, multithreading, static, thread-safety

Suppose, I have static setter and getter like:

```
private static List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void setResult(String result) {
    result.add(result);
}

public static List<String> getResult() {
    return result;
}

public static void clearResult() {
    result.clear();
}
```

I want to know if setResult() is operating from a thread and getResult() is calling from different threads and clearResult() is calling from a different thread, then what will happen? Is this functions are thread safe? will getResult() return right value?

One more thing, in mid while if i call clearResult() and thread which continiuos checking getResult(), will it get right value??

if not then what should i do??

Comment: Depends on thread safety of ArrayList rather than your code I think. Since all of them operate on the one reference.

Comment: No, and you can't guarantee it'll stay that way, either: you export your reference to `result`, so other threads can have some fun with that.  There's "threadsafe" (as in no update anomalies, making certain operations atomic) and "use safe" (essentially less-granular threadsafety to fit application needs).  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `ArrayList` is *not thread-safe*, it should not be directly used in multi-threaded way without any synchronization as it may fail unexpectedly.

You can use `Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList);` and depend on that for thread safety.

But on a static arraylist with locks there can be a lot of contention, so you may even use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) if you are traversing more often than mutating the list.

Usage of `Collections.synchronizedList()`

```
private static List<String> result = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

References:

- [Correct way to synchronize ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431681/correct-way-to-synchronize-arraylist-in-java)
- [Why manual synchronization while iterating Collections.synchronizedList()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873547/need-to-manually-synchronize-the-synchronized-list-while-iteration-when-it-could)

Comment: How i use this Collections.synchronizedList(arrayList)? as you can can see my code.

Comment: Just doing it: private static List<String> result = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

i dont have to change anything else in my functions setter,getter and clear function??

Comment: no because internally synchronizedList locks on the list object itself, so it is thread-safe for normal operations like add, remove, get. But while iterating you will have to manually lock the list.

Comment: while iterating why i need another lock??

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873547/need-to-manually-synchronize-the-synchronized-list-while-iteration-when-it-could

Answer (score 3):

All three methods operate on `ArrayList` which is not a thread-safe structure. Hence, your methods are not thread-safe too. From the JavaDoc:

> **Note** that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an `ArrayList` instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.

Change the following line this way and you should be fine:

```
private static List<String> result = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could syncronize your `List` with a guard object:

```
private static List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
private static Object       guard  = new Object();

public static void setResult(String result) {
    syncronized (guard) {
        result.add(result);
    }
}

public static List<String> getResult() {
    syncronized (guard) {
        return result;
    }
}

public static void clearResult() {
    syncronized (guard) {
        result.clear();
    }
}
```